# i am trying to calculate overtime get the result from table basic sallary do equasion to calcuate it

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I am trying to calculate over time to add it to salary the overtime time stored in table attendance and the salary is stored in other table contain total basic hourly
I want to get the result from the 2 tables display them in java another store in another table for future reference

```
int Eid = Integer.parseInt(jTextField2.getText());
try{  
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");  
    Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hr","root","adam");

    String query="SELECT *  FROM sallary where Eid ="+Eid +";"
    java.sql.PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;
    preparedStatement = con.prepareStatement(query);
    String select="select 83 *((time_to_sec(sum(overtime)) /60)/60)from att where Eid="+Eid +";";

    java.sql.PreparedStatement preparedStatement2 = null;
    preparedStatement2 = con.prepareStatement(select);

    int eid;
    double basic ,total,hourly;
    ResultSet rs2 = preparedStatement2.executeQuery();

    ResultSet rs = preparedStatement.executeQuery();

    double overtime=rs2.getDouble(1);

    // I tried this on MySQL command line it worked, however on java its error:
    // the right syntax to use near 'sum(overtime)' at line 2

    eid =rs.getInt("Eid");
    basic =rs.getDouble("basic");
    total=rs.getDouble("total");
    hourly=rs.getDouble("hourly");
    Object[] row = {eid,basic,total,hourly,overtime};

    model = (DefaultTableModel) st.getModel();

    model.addRow(row);   

} catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(payroll.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
```

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: sql syntax error the right syntax to use near 'sum(overtime)' at line 2

Answer (score 0):

The actual error message you got was something like "See the manual for your version of MySQL for the right syntax to use near 'sum(overtime)' at line 2." This error message tells you exactly what you need to do.

Looking at the manual:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html

You can see that the SELECT statement syntax does not include a semicolon at the end.

The semicolon is a statement separator, useful when you give multiple statements at the console. JDBC queries are one statement at a time, so the semicolon makes no sense and is a syntax error.

By the way, you should leave out the statement `Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");`. There is simply no need for it. It was needed in earlier versions, but has been unnecessary for the last 15 years or so.